# Find which characters are invalid when using ng-invalid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing a web app using AngularJS, but I have a problem. I'm trying to use ng-invalid to validate forms input, but I want to accept strings with some characters, for example the **'** character.

All the forms in the page are validated after the press on a button via a function. Down there the code:

```html
<textarea pattern class="form-control" maxlength="{{maxlengthDomanda}}" placeholder='{{domanda.domanda | decodeAccent}}' ng-model="domanda.risposta" 
                                        ng-class="{'invalid-restituzione': isInvalidRestituzione(domanda)}"
                                        ng-required="sezione.modificabile && domanda.abilitato && domanda.obbligatorio && !domanda.restituzione"
```

```js
$scope.checkInvalidPattern = function(form) {
                let invalidParse = $('.ng-invalid-parse');
                return form.$invalid && invalidParse != undefined && invalidParse[0] != undefined;
            }
```

How can i force ng-invalid to validate some characters?